# How to design the parameter if the type of parameter should be an abstract class

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I'm design a chating App, and it's message has many type , for example : `text`, `image`, `card`, and the card message is very differect than the `text` message.
I don't want to create easy method to handle each message , because the message will be lose if the client doesn't support that message type(I want it to show "unsupported message type" instead of nothing happened)

What should I do on server side?

```
public async Task GroupMessage(string groupId, IMessage message) // the IMessage will lose many thing
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that what's coming from the client isn't anything but some string data. SignalR has to bind that to the type in your handler. Therefore, all you're left with is `IMessage`, not something like `Text` or `Image`.

For this, you have no choice but to have different handlers, one for each type. That is the only way you can bind all the data, and then successfully interact with that data. You cannot use an abstract class or interface, unless you are fine with only having data that exists on that class or interface.

Comment: I wonder can I use just string to receive json string, and process them dynamicly, or  use an custom jsonConverter